# onCreate and Initialization in Android

Tags: android

My application should load some data when it start at first time, but it should do not load again when it resumes, when I do that loading on `onCreate` methods, if user changes orientation, that process do again, I do not want this, I need to run loading only once, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: you have to overridde onconfigurationchange method in the activity

Comment: @HarshDevChandel - Can you elaborate?  I'm a bit confused as to why so many people seem to think that the answer to "I want something to only happen once" is "set your activity to ignore/not restart on orientation changes". Won't there be other cases that might result in the data getting loaded a second time that have nothing to do with changing the device orientation?

Comment: when orientation changes the oncreate function is called again in the activty if you don't want this to happen  you overide the onconfigchange method if you want to do something you can check here wheather the mode is landscape or potriat and do whatever you want

Comment: @HarshDevChandel - Right, I understand that orientation changes will cause `onCreate()` to be called again by default.  However, is it the case that there are no _other_ scenarios that also cause `onCreate()` to be called again?

Comment: Oncreate is only called when you first time go to the activity and it is called again if the activity is destroyed or finished and you call it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple! Just put:

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside activity tag in which you require such functionality.

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="Test"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set some flag when you load the data, and only load the data when the flag is not set.  For instance:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);  

if (! preferences.getBoolean("dataLoaded")) {
    loadData();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("dataLoaded", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

This will ensure that the data is only loaded once per *install*.  If you want to load the data once per application *instance/run*, then the solution is even simpler.  In that case, you could just have a `public static` flag somewhere instead of using `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute (`android:configChanges`) will prevent the activity from being restarted. In your case, the value for this property is 
`android:configChanges="orientation"`